# Pandas profiling sensitive data - looking to randomize sample data in profile report

Tags: pandas, sensitive-data

I am working with sensitive data. Sample data in the profile report shows the first 5 rows from the dataset. If you are looking at a profile report for columns with `first_name`, `last_name`, and SSN, you can stitch together 5 people's PII.

I was able to suppress the Sample Data tab with:

```
 profile = ProfileReport(df, title="Profiling Report", samples={"head": 0, "tail": 0})
```

However, when you click `More details` the sample data (first 5 rows) is still displayed.

I was then able to suppress additional data in the report with:

```
 df.profile_report(sensitive=True)
```

This is swinging the pendulum too far in the other direction. The distribution of values and other key output is being masked.

Is there a way to simply have the sample data be 5 records selected at random?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Use Faker and create truly fake data representative of your actual data

Comment: I'm trying to profile my actual data. I want a summarized view of the data, but I cannot expose PII. Looking for the output of the profile report to either suppress just the sample data (because it is showing the first 5 actual rows of data) or choose the sample data from random entries in the column. This would not expose PII in my metadata. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isnt't.
AS per their documentation, they only 2 sections - First and last records. You can configure how many records you want to shown but not how they are selected to be depicted (the sections are called First and Last).

I would recommend asking for that feature if that's something that matters for what you are developing.